# SQL insert list of values in one column dynamicallly

Tags: mysql

I would like to execute a insert query once for inserting multiple list of records in one column

```
INSERT INTO Table (col1, col2, col3) 
VALUES (val1, val2, listVal3);
```

The third column only is the list

```
listVal3 is a list of ids from request
```

Is it possible to execute to a query like above to insert multiple records 
in one column dynamically, if so please help me, thanks.

Comment: what database? what column types?

Comment: mysql database.

Comment: what do you mean `dynamicallly`, how did `listVal3` value passed or created?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: It's a **really bad idea** to stick multiple values into a single cell - it violates even the **first normal form** of database design - I would **strongly recommend** not to do this - use the proper relational tools available to handle these 1:n relationships

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to create several records having the same values in the first two columns and taking the third column values from table `request`? In that case the following statement might be useful:

```
INSERT INTO Table (col1, col2, col3) 
SELECT 'val1', 'val2', id from request
WHERE ... --- (some conditions)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concat the listVal3 values.

```
INSERT INTO `tmp_tbl2` (col1, col2, col3) 
VALUES (val1, val2, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM request WHERE ....))
```